# Are there paths of non-degenerate $2$-forms joining two symplectic structures on open $4$-manifolds?

Tags: symplectic-topology

There is a Theorem of Conolly, L$\hat{\text{e}}$ and Ono which states that on a closed simply-connected $4$-manifold two cohomologous symplectic forms can be joined by a path of non-degenerate $2$-forms.

I was wondering is there any open analogue of this theorem? For example:

Let $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ be two cohomologous symplectic structures on an open simply-connected $4$-manifold $M$ which are equal on the complement of some compact set. Are there any results on the existence of a path $\{\omega_t\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ of non-degenerate $2$-forms joining $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ such that all $\omega_t$ are equal on the complement of some compact set?

I am especially interested in the case $M=\mathbb{R}^4$.